# Yii2 CRUD and Pagination

Tags: pagination, yii2, crud

I am using Yii2 with Pjax for index/gridview listing. using pjax pagination , search all working fine without postback to server.

My problem starts now, 
suppose i am on page number 2, i have clicked on edit record of that 2nd page list, i reach to update view, i have done changes and saved, now i am redirected to view , now i clicked on index link from breadcrumbs.

i want to reach to page number 2 of index rather then 1st page.

Traditional process for this is get refereeing page params an append that in breadcrumbs.

But is there any simple approach to this problem where i can write few lines of code and its applied to every where in backend?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255851/yii2-gridview-save-filters-value-in-session?answertab=active#tab-top i have sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following Code in every controller of actionIndex() rest all things will take care

```
    $searchModel = new CentervideosSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    /*Code insertion block begin*/
    $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;      
    if (count($params) <= 1) 
    {
        $params = Yii::$app->session['customerparams'];
        if(isset(Yii::$app->session['customerparams']['page']))
            $_GET['page'] = Yii::$app->session['customerparams']['page'];
        if(isset(Yii::$app->session['customerparams']['per-page']))
            $_GET['per-page'] = Yii::$app->session['customerparams']['per-page'];   
    } 
    else 
    {
        Yii::$app->session['customerparams'] = $params;
    }
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);
   /*Code insertion block Ends*/
```

Answer (score 1):

For remembering grid filter, pages i use [yii2-grid-view-state](https://github.com/thrieu/yii2-grid-view-state)

Comment: I am not sure why i need to use this grid, i dont want to remember grid view state as on grid page during navigation everything is working fine. but when i edit Record #39 from page 2, i go to Update view, and from there when i click on breadcrumbs i am coming to page 1 again,

Comment: i tried to follow instruction in your given solution, 

But not able to understand where to create 1st step? i mean to say on which Path?

Comment: yii2-grid-view-state  in 1. step create extended GridView class

Comment: its still not useful, refer my answer above, its really easy, 100% native and working fine....

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store page only, isn't it quite easy to pass `page` param into your view url (`<model/view>`) like `<model>/view?id=<id>&page=<page>`?

in your `index.php` view, edit your ActionColumn as follow:

```
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            return \yii\helpers\Url::to([$action, 'id' => $model->id, 'page' => Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('page', null)]);
        },
    ],
```

As you can see, I'm getting page param from request url and pass it to models' action buttons (to all buttons, but in your question it would be enough for `view` button of course)

And when you click to `view` model, in our Controller we need to get that `page` value and pass it to our `view.php` view (in order to place it in breadcrumbs).

Our ModelController:

```
    public function actionView($id, $page = null)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }
```

And finally `view.php` view will get the `page` value, and populate the `index` url (if not null):

```
/* @var $page int */

$this->title = $model->name;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Index', 'url' => ['index', 'page' => $page]];
```

So when you press the Index breadcrumb, it will open the page, where you entered from.

---

Some advantages againts session implementation (@user1764431 solution):

- Each of your tab can return to it's own last page
- Simple and stupid solution

Some disadvantages:

- If you need to store some filter params, url could stretch very long

Comment: This solution is tedious overall and requires to write so many lines.. I have found more smallest and easiest solution.